# Xcode connect to the MS SQL database

Tags: ios, objective-c, sql-server, swift, macos

I have an existing database up and running on the remote `MS SQL server`, and I want to be able to communicate and interact with that database from `Xcode`. I am writing an application for `OS X` in `Swift`, and the data that the application should use, is stored in that remote database.

The problem is, I can't seem to find any `Swift` library that could connect to the `MS SQL server` based database. So far, I have only found this open-source library: [SQLClient in Objective-C](https://objcsharp.wordpress.com/2013/10/15/an-open-source-sql-server-library-for-ios/), but it's quite difficult to have it set, especially as I am not familiar with the `Objective-C`.

Also, I keep seeing this `Core-Data` library being mentioned anytime there is some communication with the database, but as far as I understand `Core-Data` doesn't know how to connect to the `MS SQL` database.

Does anyone have any experience in connecting the `Xcode Swift app` to the remote `MS SQL` database? How should one do this? Any kind of advice is more than welcome, because right now I am kind of stuck with this problem.

Comment: You should clarify that you don't want XCode to connect to the database, but your application, written in Swift

Comment: Did you found the solution without web service?

Comment: Hello @Zwiebl! Did you find a solution for this please? I am exactly like you, wanting desperately to get my MacOS (OSX) to connect to Sql Server, but can't find any readable or understandable instruction anywhere. Please help if you found one or point me to a link I can start digging. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The ideal way is to write webservices in any serverside language such as php, asp etc. The webservices will communicae with your mysql database and you swift code will communicate to the webservices.

Comment: I know the ideal way is to write a webservice, but the SQL server is remote, I only have the connection string to the database. I am not sure whether I am even able to write a webservice for a remote server? I only know the server domain, and user/password parameters. I dont think writing a webservice is an option here?

Comment: Yes you can write webservices for remote database. The server domain is your server host and you have the credentials

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to write a webservice with php for example to consume mysql data and provide a json/xml response :  this is an example of code that can help you to getdata from Database and parse it to json  .

```
function getOneAdminByUserName($cin){

require('connect.php');

//fetch table rows from mysql db
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE cin= '".$cin."'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection)); 


if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    $myArray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   array_push( $myArray , $row);
}
return json_encode($myArray);   
//return json_encode(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
}
else{
return "no";
}
```

Then you can consume service on your ios app with [AFnetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

```
 NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/resources/123.json"];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really bad for an application (mobile, web, any client) to directly have access to any database for security issues. Clients really should not be accessing the database, which is often holding very private/secure data. It opens up vulnerabilities (i.e., sql injection attack).

A set of web services written in php or java or some back-end technology is a more secure, scalable system. These web services can connect to the database and retrieve data. Your iOS application can call the web services and receive the data..for example in the form of XML or JSON.

So better you to use webservice.

Also coredata can use below 4 persistant store
[image]

Comment: The thing is that server is on a remote location, I don't have access to the server-side. The database is ran on a server that is situated at the University, and I was only given the connection string, i.e. the paremeters to connect to it. All I know about the server side is this:

data source={server_domain}\SQL2012,3000;initial catalog={my_catalog};persist security info=True;user id={username};password={password};

Am I still able to write a web-service?

Comment: yeah you can write your service if u have the connecion string !