# How to connect an iOS app to an existing database

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, xcode

I'm about to make an iOS app for a company that will need to access an already existing database table on SQL Server. All I want to do is make a connection to the already existing database table and compare it to a data item within the app - but I cant figure out how to create this connection using Objective-C. All of the information I've found deals with making a database yourself using sqlite and then importing the table data into the sqlLite database, but I've already got a live database on SQLServer I need to connect to.

this question: [ios app: How to efficiently use an existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072382/ios-app-how-to-efficiently-use-an-existing-database) was very similar to mine and had no resolution.

this one is also similar: [Xcode connect to the MS SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717020/xcode-connect-to-the-ms-sql-database) it suggests to use a webservice - but I'm using Objective-c - will there be an issue getting my Objective-c code to communicate with the webservice?

I'd really like to do it without a webservice but it doesn't seem like an option.

I keep reading about RESTFULapi's but there is absolutely no documentation that I can found that will explain how to perform anything similar to what I'm talking about (feel free to point me to the resource if you disagree)

Any recommendations would be appreciated

Comment: Very quick answer is that you need a backend api developer who know how to interact with SQL server and know how to deploy this api on cloud/on premise.Java/Javascript/Python/Ruby/Go/Rust can handle tasks like api build.

Comment: @CharlieCai I am the only developer so this isn't an option

Comment: There is no way  app can  talk to sql server directly in my opinion.You may have to learn as least one backend api development.

Comment: So you can't make a SQL connection in the backend? I've made SQL connections in C#, im just bewildered as to how that's not an option in swift/objective C

Comment: Sure,you can make SQL connections in C#.Swift/Objective C,in most cases,is a client side language.However you can still use them for backend api development,but I would not suggest you do that because Swift/OC backend development is not as mature/easy as other languages

Comment: Looks like you should use some framework that allows you to work with SQL API directly.

Answer (score -1):

I guess I post the solution in very abstract level.

1. Install database in Xcode.
2. If you are unable to do so, then keep your Front end separate (Xcode and Swift) and do programming Back end (which could be python+database+Flask).
3. If you are following me so far, then you can send data from your backend to web services, and you can grab those data from web services to your frontend and vice and versa.